# Offset() not working on button click

Tags: javascript

I want the window to scroll down to a certain div on a button click.

```
$('button').click(function(event){
  var offset = $('div').offset();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(window).scrollTop(offset.top);
});
```

When I input this code in the console, it works perfectly but then doesn't work in the actual browser test.

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Did you add the script after the elements or wrap in `document.ready`? Did you check for errors in the console?

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/fwvdz61n/2/

Comment: It's outside of the document.ready because of an ajax call attributed to it. I think that's why adding a setTimeout function makes it work

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped it in a setTimeout function and that seemed to work.